# Load bootstrap datatable on dropdown change

Tags: datatables

I am completely new to jquery/bootstrap Datatables and I am trying to use one in an application.

I have a modal popup in which i have a select dropdown. When select dropdown value changes i would like 
to make a call to server and display a dataTable grid in modal.
Initially when modal popup loads i don't want to display grid, not even empty one.
I want to display grid only when dropdown value changes.
Grid has to then reload every time dropdown value changes.

I have been trying combinations of parameters but it's not working.
I tried using 'iDeferLoading', 'bDeferRender', table.ajax.reload() etc but it's not working as expected.
With below code grid is always loaded when modal popup loads first time.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        var table = null;
        $("#userType").change(function() {
            var userType = $(this).val();
            if (userType == "test") {
                table = $('#example').DataTable({
                  'ajax': {
                     'url': '/test/getAllPlatforms?itemId=' + $('#itemId').val(),
                     "dataSrc": ''
                  },
                  "columns": [
                              { "data": "selected" },
                              { "data": "id" },
                              { "data": "platformName" },
                              { "data": "itemPrice" },
                              { "data": "revenueShare" }

                          ],

                  columnDefs: [ {
                        orderable: false,
                        className: 'dt-body-center',
                        targets:   0,
                        'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                            console.log(data + " : " + full);
                            var checked = "";
                            if (data == true) {
                                checked = "checked";
                            }
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '" ' + checked + '>';
                        }
                    }

                  ],
                    select: {
                        style:    'os',
                        selector: 'td:first-child'
                    },
                    order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
                    'iDeferLoading': 1,
                    'bDeferRender': true
               });
            }
        });
    });
```